# Store virtual user's roles outside core database

Tags: user-profile

The roles and properties of a virtual user are stored in the `ClientData` table in the core database by default. 
I would like to store them somewhere else ideally in Redis with the rest of shared and private session. Is deriving the abstract `ClientDataStore` class the only way to do this, has anyone successfully done this?